# elasticsearch rails searching models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, mapping, analyzer, elasticsearch-rails

I am using elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model gem for searching products in my rails app.

I want to make my search case insensitive and must be independent of pluralization. I researched a lot on google but got a hunch on how to do it using analyzer but not success. So I had to post a new question.

Here is my product model where I want to search to take place

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :sub_category
  has_many :variations


  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball'
      indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
      indexes :category, analyzer: 'snowball'
    end
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json(only: [:name, :description, :brand, :color, :make, :style, :gender],
            include: { category: { only: :name}, sub_category: {only: :name}}
            )
  end

  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search({
        query: { query_string: {
            query: query,
            default_operator: "AND"
          }},
      })
  end

end
```

1. My questions are how do I do search irrespective of pluralization?
2. tshirt, T-shirt, Tshirts should all match.

Above all I never found any explanation of the following block given below

```
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
      indexes :category, analyzer: 'snowball'
    end
  end
```

what is the exact purpose of this block for searching.

what does mappings dynamic: 'false' means?

what does indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', index_options: 'offsets'
means?

What are the other options that could be added in this block with a little bit of explanation would be of great help for me.

Any links for further research is also helpful.

Thanks